# PowerBI month as number

Tags: date, powerbi, dax

I just simplify and rephrase my question as previously it was more complicated compared to what I really needed.

So I need a solution for how I can see/show the "Month" from a Date hierarchy as a number in any filter or visualization.

That's my simple date hierarchy with Year/Month/Day. I only use the month as I work with periods in my report.

[image: 1]

Now if I use "Month" from the hierarchy it is shown by filters and visualizations with the name of the month.:

[image: 2]

I would like to see the months as a number.
Also, it is important to use the "Month" from the hierarchy as many DAX use it for calculations.

Could you please help?

Thanks,

András

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not revealing the data model but some screen shoots only it's kind of guess work trying to help you.

In your Periods table you could add a calculated column from

```
Month Number = MONTH(Periods[Date])
```

and use this field in your visual instead.

Comment: Hi, I may overcomplicate the question. To keep it simple I have under the Periods table a date hiearchy. What I need is when I add the "Month" from that hiearchy to a visualization I would like to see that as number and not the name of the month. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, it is possible.

Comment: May you can tell me how? I could not find the answer to that.